# Detect contour from point grid

Tags: algorithm, contour

Suppose we have a grid of points (which can also be very dense 10000x10000) like the one in the figure in which the points are marked with two different colors.
[image]

What is the best algorithm from a performance point of view that allows me to reconstruct the outline of the red dots connecting the points of the grid itself? Here is the result I expect.

[image]
In the figure the contour is continuous, but in reality I'm also fine with finding a stepped contour that connects the border points between the red and blue ones. In general the region of red points is always connected but may not be convex. The algorithm will be added inside a simulation routine, so it should be as fast as possible.

Comment: Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: I agree that the question is a bit generic and doesn't go into detail, but it's intentional. I just wanted to know if there are any known algorithms in the literature to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: This seems to be out of the scope of StackOverflow; [Which Stack Exchange website for machine learning and computational algorithms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms) has a list of StackExchange sites that might be more helpful to you, if you can't get the help you need from here